# Compile Groovy in VSCode

Tags: groovy, visual-studio-code

I've found the `vscode-groovy` extension that does the formatting and highlighting, but I'm really having trouble getting the compiler/debugger configured.

I figure I could just point `JAVA_HOME` to my Groovy compiler, but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem, so I did the following steps:

1. Installation of Groovy. Firstly, I've installed the [latest stable pack from the Groovy website](http://groovy-lang.org/install.html). This is basically downloading the pack and unzipping it to a certain local folder.
2. Add Groovy bin to PATH variable. Just add the bin folder of the unzipped Groovy pack to the environment variable `PATH`.
3. Install the `Code Runner extension` for Visual Studio Code. This extension can be downloaded from the [VS marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner). If this is done, then you can at least run the groovy script already. Just open the context menu of the file in the VS Code explorer and click `Run code`.

If you want to debug the script, then you should put it in a java class and debug it as [described here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging).

Comment: I'm sorry for the necro-post, but when I tried this, it didn't work...
It couldn't find groovy, even if I put it on the `PATH`
 :'(

Answer (score 4):

My way as of today:

1. Install `Java`, `Gradle`, `Visual Studio Code` with extensions `vscjava.vscode-java-pack` and `richardwillis.vscode-gradle-extension-pack`.
2. In an empty folder, run `gradle init`, Type of project `application`, Implementation language `Groovy`, use defaults for the rest.
3. Open folder in Visual Studio Code.
4. In left toolbar, select the `Gradle` icon, expand `app`, `tasks`, `application`, select `run` and click the icon `Run task`.

Comment: Thanx, sir ! It seems to be the only relevant way to get Groovy applications to run and debug in NetBeans !